# Concatenate div tag to db result

Tags: php, zend-framework, concatenation

I am getting some data from a database table `tableA` and need to return the `'name'` column inside a div tag.

```
$divtag1 = '<div style="color:#1569C7; font-weight:bold">';
$select = $this->select()
->from(array('ta' => 'tableA'),
array('ta.id', 
      'name' => new Zend_Db_Expr("concat($divtag1 . ta.name . '</div>')"),
      'date' => new Zend_Db_Expr("date(ta.date)")
));

$result = $this->getAdapter()->fetchAll($select);
```

I am getting an error :

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '
. ta.name . '
') AS `name`, da'
```

The problem is that the concat() function is interpreting the quotes inside the $divtag1 for itself and I do not want that.
Can someone help me in getting this right?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
'name' => new Zend_Db_Expr("concat('$divtag1', ta.name, '</div>')"),
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. What you suggested worked but after I made another correction - `'name' => new Zend_Db_Expr("concat('$divtag1', ta.name, '</div>')"),` ie, instead of dots, I should have used commas.

Comment: And that was exactly my suggestion :) see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat

Comment: Can you also advice something to eliminate the step of assigning the string to $divtag1 ?

Comment: It's not a common practice to concatenate HTML within the query. You should avoid that if you are not after a quick and dirty hack.

Comment: But is it a good idea instead to loop through the results returned from db and then concatenate the div tags? Or is there another possible solution?

Answer (score 0):

There were two corrections:

1. Quoting the $divtag1 variable; Thank you @Parahat Melayev
2. Using comma's in concat() instead of dots.

Final solution is :

```
$divtag1 = '<div style="color:#1569C7; font-weight:bold">';
$select = $this->select()
->from(array('ta' => 'tableA'),
array('ta.id', 
      'name' => new Zend_Db_Expr("concat($divtag1 , ta.name , '</div>')"),
      'date' => new Zend_Db_Expr("date(ta.date)")
));



$result = $this->getAdapter()->fetchAll($select);
```